# Heroku not loading for different layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using rail 4 on heroku. I have an admin panel with a separate layout from the front page. When I deploy to heroku, it takes forever for this admin panel to load the first time. I usually get 4 Application Errors before I get through. However, any other page on the site (with the default application layout) loads fine.

Should I be enabling some sort of configuration for multiple layouts? I have an AdminController with this in it

```
layout "admin_layout"
```

Then I have an admin_layout.html.erb file in the layouts folder with this in the head

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin_application", media: "all" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "admin_application" %>
```

Pretty much the same as the regular application.html.erb file. Anyone have ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added admin_application.css and admin_application.js in application.rb to the list of assets to pre-compile.  It could be that you have on-demand asset compiling enabled and Heroku is compiling these assets on the fly every time because the weren't pre-compiled during the deploy.